# Print a message if excerpt is empty after posts have been publish/update!

Tags: posts, excerpt, publish

I don't think I can make the excerpt required, but if anyone knows a workaround please share.
At least I want to print a message if excerpt is empty after posts have been publish/update, maybe a red notification to be more visible!

I use [this script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14088/9023) to show excerpt box by default!

Comment: Using the first characters of the post for the excerpt will not work? Because you're going to have to override that behavior as well if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the [has_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_excerpt) function to test for excerpt content and if it is not filled in you could display a message.

**Example:**

```
if( has_excerpt() ) {
    the_excerpt();
} else {
    echo '<p>Please enter the excerpt.</p>';
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this code?... this looks like a frontend function for themes, I need it in the backend, in wp-admin/new page panel :)

Answer (score 0):

For updateing, you could use the `pre_post_update` action hook, and if there is no excerpt you could prevent the post being updated and display an error message, but it doesn't look like you can stop the new post from being created.